# How to create a table in Rstudio presentation

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, rpres

I'm trying to create a table in an RStudio .Rpres file.  Below is what I have at this point from online searching but the alignment is not correct.  Is this the best method?  Any suggestions on the alignment?

```
Test
=========================================================
| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |

  : Demonstration of simple table syntax.
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `knitr::kable` to print your `data.frame`

````
Test
========================================================

```{r, echo=FALSE}
my_df <- iris
knitr::kable(head(my_df))
```
````

@alignments:
I tried using `align = c('l', 'r', 'c', 'r', 'l')` as described in `?kable`
but it did not work. Maybe this is a bug.

Output of

```
knitr::kable(head(iris), align = c('l', 'r', 'c', 'r', 'l'))

|Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width| Petal.Length | Petal.Width|Species |
|:------------|-----------:|:------------:|-----------:|:-------|
|5.1          |         3.5|     1.4      |         0.2|setosa  |
|4.9          |         3.0|     1.4      |         0.2|setosa  |
|4.7          |         3.2|     1.3      |         0.2|setosa  |
|4.6          |         3.1|     1.5      |         0.2|setosa  |
|5.0          |         3.6|     1.4      |         0.2|setosa  |
|5.4          |         3.9|     1.7      |         0.4|setosa  |
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`pander`](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#cell-alignment) example:

````
```{r}
df <- replicate(3, sample(letters, 3))
colnames(df) <- rep('foobar', 3)
pander::pander(df, justify = c('right', 'left', 'center'))
```
````

Or specifying a global alignment for all columns (which can be a smart function as well BTW):

````
```{r}
set.alignment('right')
pander::pander(df)
```
````

Both results in a correctly formatted markdown table that renders fine in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get `align` to work by including the `format = "html"` parameter in the function call, so in the example discussed above by FlooO:

```
knitr::kable(head(iris), format = "html", align = c('l', 'r', 'c', 'r', 'l'))
```

gave me the desired result