# How to display R data frame in generated PowerPoint

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, kableextra, officer

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Table

```{r table, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  ungroup()  # %>%
  # kable() %>%
  # kable_styling()
```
````

I'm working off the repro above. I'd like to present the mtcars calculated data frame in a kable or kableExtra fashion, like this:

[image: kableExtra]

Instead the table outputs in the following console format:

```
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##     cyl     n
##   <dbl> <int>
## 1     4    11
## 2     6     7
## 3     8    14
```

How do I make my R PowerPoint tables pretty, and even better, editable in PowerPoint?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267258/how-to-create-a-table-in-rstudio-presentation

Comment: @Yilun Zhang thanks for the tip. I think that only works for HTML format, not PowerPoint. I did try anyway with the YAML `always_allow_html: yes` but the table was more of an ASCII format table than anything resembling kable or kableExtra.

Comment: I've never had to output to PowerPoint (hope I never will!), but the PowerPoint chapter of the RMarkdown book points to the table printing section of the HTML chapter: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#data-frame-printing

Comment: @camille thanks that does help, unfortunately most of these HTML options don't work in PowerPoint presentations. I will use that for my normal HTML files though. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the PowerPoint section links to the HTML table examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `flextable` package. It's support powerpoint_presentation output with R Markdown. You will find below an example :

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Table

```{r table, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)
mtcars[1:5,1:4] %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
  flextable() %>%
  set_header_labels(rowname = "") %>% 
  add_header_row(values = c("", "Group 1", "Group 2"), 
                 colwidths = c(1, 2, 2)) %>% 
  theme_zebra() %>% autofit()
```
````

Comment: Hello @David Gohel I tried this but it complained about the PANDOC version, I upgraded it in the terminal (Ubuntu) but still does not work. Any idea how to work around that?